# Bootstrap 4 Side Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Taking a look at the Bootstrap 4 documentation, there is clearly a left aligned navigation bar on the side which takes the full height of its parent as the main content scrolls in the center. I've been inspecting elements trying to reverse engineer it, but try as I might, I can't seem to get my column to be full height. Any ideas of how to implement this using the Bootstrap 4 utility classes?

Comment: I haven't read it yet, but fwiw, [SimpleTalk article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/first-look-bootstrap-4-navigation-bars/).

Comment: @wazz That's not what I'm looking for. Sidebar navigation ...

Answer (score 1):

Look like they are using some custom CSS and not built in Bootstrap classes.

If you inspect the element you'll see there is a class of the main container called `bd-sidebar`. Looking at the CSS rules you'll find something that looks like this.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.bd-sidebar {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 4rem;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
}
```

Taking you through that line by line.
The top line is the media query, so this whole rule will only apply at screen width of 768px or above.

`position:sticky` - These guys can explain it better than me - https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/ - Above that is a vendor-prefixed version.

`top:4rem` - Pushes the top of it down by 4 ['relative ems'](https://css-tricks.com/rem-global-em-local/). This makes it clear the top nav bar.

`z-index:1000` - makes sure it sits above and below certain content.

And here comes the clever bit!

`height: calc(100vh - 4 rem)`

This [`calc`ulates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) the height of this element by removing 4 relative ems (remember the nav bar height we wanted to clear earlier) from 100`vh`. A `vh` is a viewport height and is a percentage of the full viewport height. For example, 10vh will resolve to 10% of the current viewport height (source: https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

Comment: Do you see how there is a sidebar to the left that is full height, a content div in the middle that is full height, and all the way to the right some overhang that exceeds the max-width?